# maior/menor em vetores

Tags: c

Fiz algumas modificações mo meu codigo, ele se apresenta em modificações no fim do post la irei modificar quando achar necessario.

olá, estou fazendo um exercicio da faculdade, ele é bem simples, porem, estou tendo certa dificuldade nele, o exercicio pede para escrever dois vetores de 5 possições e imprimir um vetor resultante ordenando os elementos em ordem decrescente (elementos são do tipo **int**), abaixo o codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int vet1[5], vet2[5], rvet[10];
    int i, j, k, n1=0, n2=0;


    for(i=0; i<=4; i++)//Lê o vet1
    {

        printf("Digite para posicao %d do vet1:\n", n1++);
        scanf("%i", &vet1[i]);
    }

    printf("Obrigado, agora:\n");

    for(j=0; j<=4; j++)//Lê vet2
    {
        printf("Digite para posicao %d do vet2:\n", n2++);
        scanf("%d", &vet2[j]);

    }

    i=0;
    j=0;
    for(k=0;k<=9;k++)//Ordena os vetores
    {
        rvet[k]=i>j ? vet1[i++] : vet2[j++];

            printf("vet[%d]:%d\n", k, rvet[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

minha maior dificuldade é no **for da linha 28**(ou o 3º for), não consigo pensar em um algoritmo melhor, então postei uma impressão que alinha primeiro o vet2 e depois o vet1.
Eu estava pensando em fazer menor e maior porem quando eu modifico o algoritmo ele sempre perde os dados guardado no vetor 1 e 2 e ai aparece outros numeros aleatorios.
se alguem puder me ajudar obrigado... meu programa não tem errors e nem warning testei no code::blocks e no dev C++

MODIFICAÇÕES:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int vet1[5], vet2[5], rvet[10];
    int i, j, k, x, y, n1=0, n2=0, aux=0;


    for(i=0; i<=4; i++)//Lê o vet1
    {

        printf("Digite para posicao %d do vet1:\n", n1++);
        scanf("%i", &vet1[i]);
    }


    fflush(stdin);
    system("cls");
    printf("Obrigado, agora:\n");

    for(j=0; j<=4; j++)//Lê vet2
    {
        printf("Digite para posicao %d do vet2:\n", n2++);
        scanf("%d", &vet2[j]);

    }

    fflush(stdin);
    system("cls");


    for(k=0; k<=4; k++)//preenche as 5 primeiras possições com vet1;
    {
            rvet[k]=vet1[i++];
    }

    for(k=5; k<=9; k++)
    {
        rvet[k]=vet2[j++];
    }   


    for(y=0; y<=9; y++)//coloca em ordem decrescente
    {
        for(k=x+1; k<=9; k++)
        {
            if(rvet[k]<rvet[x])
            {
                aux=rvet[x];
                rvet[x]=rvet[y];
                rvet[y]=aux;
            }
        }
    }

    for(k=0; k<=9; k++)
    {
        printf("%d->%d\n", k, rvet[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

aqui eles imprime primeiro o vet1 e depois o vet2.

Comment: Você quer que o rvet, fique ordenado de forma decrescente?

Comment: isso mesmo diego

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para isso, creio que a forma mais eficiente seria criar um terceiro vetor com tamanho 10, inserir os valores dos 2 vetores anteriores neste terceiro, e então realizar a ordenação.

Para isso:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int vet1[5], vet2[5], rvet[10], n1=0, n2=0, aux=0;

for(int i=0; i<=4; i++) //Lê o vet1
{

    printf("Digite para posicao %d do vet1:\n", n1++);
    scanf("%i", &vet1[i]);
}

printf("Obrigado, agora:\n");

for(int j=0; j<=4; j++)//Lê vet2
{
    printf("Digite para posicao %d do vet2:\n", n2++);
    scanf("%d", &vet2[j]);

}

//intercalando os vetores aqui
for(int k=0; k<=4; k++)
{
rvet[k] = vet1[k]; //preenche as primeiras 5 posições
}

for(int k=5; k<=9; k++)
{
rvet[k] = vet2[k-5]; //preenche as próximas 5.
}

//Ordenação bubble sort
 for(int x = 0; x <= 9; x++ )
 {
   for(int y = x + 1; y <= 9; y++ ) // sempre 1 elemento à frente
    {
     // se o x for menor que a próxima posição do vetor, o x passa pra frente (ordem decrescente)
     if (rvet[x] < rvet[y] )
     {
      aux = rvet[x];
      rvet[x] = rvet[y];
      rvet[y] = aux;
     }
    }
  } // fim da ordenação
printf("*** VETOR ORDENADO ***\n");

for(int i=0; i<=9; i++)
{
  printf("%d\n", rvet[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

**Dica: quando for utilizar uma variável somente para percorrer o `for`, declare-a desta forma** `for(int var=0; var<=x; var++)`. **Assim, quando o loop acaba, a variável deixa de existir, ou seja, não é necessário atribuir 0 à mesma.**

@LeonardoV.DeGasperin nas últimas alterações feitas percebi os seguintes erros no seu código:

1 - Os vetores `vet1` e `vet2` foram preenchidos nos índices: 0, 1, 2, 3 e 4 (5 índices, lembrando que o 0 também conta). Você zerou as variáveis i e j, e depois começou a percorrer o vetor assim: `vet1[i++]`, lembrando que se i começa com 0, i++ automaticamente será 1, ignorando o índice 0. Desta forma, você passa pelos índices: 1, 2, 3, 4 e 5, sendo que no índice 5 não há nada. Olhe para o código que postei acima na parte que intercalo os vetores e perceberá a diferença.

2 - Depois que você preencher o vetor `rvet[]` não basta fazer um if para ordená-lo. A partir daqui, esqueça os vetores `vet1[]` e `vet2[]`. Para ordenar e exibir em ordem decrescente, e necessário percorrer todo o vetor `rvet[]` e organizar os números que estão dentro dele, e algo que auxilia nessa tarefa é um algoritmo chamado **[algoritmo de ordenação](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o)**. Sem o uso deste algoritmo, dificulta-se a ordenação. O que utilizei no meu código (e creio que seja o mais simples de compreender) é o **[bubble sort](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)**, mas depois recomendo a você pesquisar sobre os outros também, é interessante.

**[Aqui](http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/codigos/metodo-bolha-bubble-sort) você pode consultar o que eu utilizei para fazer essa ordenação.**.

3 - Por último, para imprimir todo o vetor ordenado de uma vez, e necessário criar outro `for`, como consta no código acima.

Qualquer dúvida, não hesite em perguntar. Abraço!

Comment: hmm irei ver, só fazendo um adendo apos o j=0; nao necessita declarar rvet[10] pois ele ja foi declarado, mas obrigado se der certo irei marcar a sua resposta =) caso contrario irei add outro comentario falando sobre os erros que acontece obrigado.

Comment: @Vitor, o seu programa intercala, mas não ordena o vetor como o OP pediu.

Comment: @Kyllopardium Obrigado pela observaçao, já alterei.

Comment: @kyllopardium eu fiz algumas alterações no post coloquei modificação abaixo dele um codigo novo porem com problema eu ainda to tendo complicações com ele caso algum dos dois puderem me ajudar, o problema conciste ainda em se os elementos do vetX for maiores q os elementos do vetY ira imprimir primeiro o vetorX na ordem dele e a seguir idem com o vetY

Comment: @VictorAlencarSantos o comentario a cima leia caso puder =) obrigado

Comment: @LeonardoV.DeGasperin consulte a resposta, alterei algums coisas

Comment: @LeonardoV.DeGasperin, olhe na linha que coloquei o comentário e faça a alteração que sugeri lá.

Comment: então @VictorAlencarSantos eu fiz aqui ta igual o seu porem ele imprime o vet1 na ordem do vet1 e depois o vet2 na ordem do vet2, e nao ordena os numeros, mas obrigado eu vou postar o codigo novo na area notificações do meu post caso queira dar uma olhada

Comment: @LeonardoV.DeGasperin amigo, seu código editado ainda está incorreto. Tente copiar todo o código que postei acima e colar na sua aplicação e rodar.

Comment: @VictorAlencarSantos quando compilei levei um susto tinha 14 erros, mas era a declarações das variaveis dos loop dos `for` ai modifiquei a declaração e funcionou, obrigado vou estudar o codigo que você fez e tentar fazer um sozinho

Comment: @LeonardoV.DeGasperin Por nada! Alguns compiladores como o Dev C++ não são tão 'amigáveis' com variáveis declaradas dentro de loops, mas é uma ótima prática para casos como este, pois economiza espaço em memória.

Comment: @VictorAlencarSantos essa parte eu nao intendi muito bem `aux = rvet[x];
      rvet[x] = rvet[y];
      rvet[y] = aux; `

Comment: @LeonardoV.DeGasperin o chat não vai funcionar pra mim, então:

Esta parte é onde organizamos os números dentro do vetor. Se  o valor contido na posição atual (`rvet[x]`) for menor que o valor contido na próxima posição (`rvet[y]`), o maior valor passa para cima. Este trecho de código apenas está mostrando que caso o número maior esteja vindo depois, ele passa a vir antes.

[este artigo](http://blogdecodigo.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/bubble-sort-de-um-jeito-bem-diferente-video/) tem uma explicação bem clara sobre isso.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16283/discussion-between-victor-alencar-santos-and-leonardo-v-de-gasperin).

Comment: @VictorAlencarSantos muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Você não fez nada com o `i` e com o `j` no seu último for e repare que mesmo que estivesse o que acredito que estava pensando em fazer estaria errado:

```
v1 : {2,5,20}  v2: {44,34,23}
v1[i]>v2[j]  => vres = [v2[j++]]
```

o problema é que como os vetores v1 e v2 não estão ordenados, eles vão ter resultados inesperados principalmente se o valor do lixo da memória for ainda inferior a um dos valores usados.

Dicas quanto ao código:

Use `#define` para não ter que escrever os valores em todos os lugares (fica bem mais fácil para modificar posteriormente).

faça a ordenacão após concatenar os dois vetores.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXVETOR 5
#define MAXRESULTADO MAXVETOR*2



void ordena(int* vetor , int tamanho){
int c,d,swap;
for (c = 0 ; c < ( tamanho - 1 ); c++)
  {
    for (d = c ; d < tamanho - c - 1; d++)
    {
      if (vetor[d] > vetor[d+1]) //Troque de > para < para alterar a forma de ordenação.
      {
        swap       = vetor[d];
        vetor[d]   = vetor[d+1];
        vetor[d+1] = swap;
      }
    }
  }
}
void imprime_vetor(int *vetor,int tamanho){
    int i=0;
    printf("[");
    for(;i<tamanho;i++){
        if(i==tamanho-1){
            printf("%d]",vetor[i]);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d,",vetor[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int vet1[MAXVETOR] = {1,4,28,34,2}, vet2[MAXVETOR]={99,23,6,3,7}, rvet[MAXRESULTADO];
    int i, j, k, n1=0, n2=0;

/*
    for(i=0; i<MAXVETOR; i++)//Lê o vet1
    {

        printf("Digite para posicao %d do vet1:\n", n1++);
        scanf("%i", &vet1[i]);
    }

    printf("Obrigado, agora:\n");

    for(j=0; j<MAXVETOR; j++)//Lê vet2
    {
        printf("Digite para posicao %d do vet2:\n", n2++);
        scanf("%d", &vet2[j]);

    }
*/
    i=0;
    j=0;
    for(k=0;k<MAXRESULTADO;k++)//Intercala os vetores
    {
        rvet[k] = vet1[k];
    }
    for(k=MAXVETOR;k<MAXRESULTADO;k++)//Intercala os vetores
    {
        rvet[k] = vet2[k-MAXVETOR];
    }
    ordena(rvet,MAXRESULTADO);
    imprime_vetor(rvet,MAXRESULTADO);
    return 0;
}
```